# Files not being listed in order

Tags: c#, directory

I'm creating a bunch of files named sequentially, from 0 to ,say, 30 using StreamWriter class. When I try to read them back in a loop, and when I compare two files, 0 gets compared with 10 and then with 11 and so on till 19 and then 0 gets compared with 2 then 21 and so on. Is there any way I can get it to compare 0 with 1, then with 2 and so on instead?
I'm reading files with Directory.GetFiles();

Thanks!

Comment: Why not create the files so that the names are xxx00, xxx01, xxx02, ... xxx09, xxx10, xxx11, ..., xxx30 ?  You should be able to accomplish this with something like `String.Format("xxx{0:00}", n)` where `n` is your file number and `xxx` is the prefix.  I might have made a syntax error since I'm on my mac and couldn't test this out, obviously :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles();` just returns a string array so it would be pretty easy to reorder them

e.g.

```
       var files = Directory.GetFiles();
       var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(s=>int.Parse( s));

        foreach (string s in orderedFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Note: you may need to use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) before the call to int.Parse and you might also want to use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead.

Comment: `s` can be `1.ext` so can you parse it to an int? Does this work?

Comment: @Kaf if you can guarantee the names are in the format #.ext then you can do `int.Parse(s.split(".")[0])`

Comment: @matt that works but Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension may just make life eaiser

Answer (score 2):

See the [MSDN page on Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx). In particlar note this:

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required.

You should get the file names and sort them yourself.

Usually the files are returned in name order, but in that case the order will be 0,1,11,12,...,2,20,21,...3 etc. You can see this if you sort by name in Windows Explorer. As somebody else has already suggested, your best bet is to pad with leading zeros. I.e. 00, 01, 02, 03, ...,10, 11, 12, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick for you. Ordered by creation time

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("YourDirectoryPath");
System.IO.FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

var sortedFiles = from f in files
                          orderby f.CreationTime ascending
                          select f;
```

Comment: +1 but using DirectoryInfo is cheating ;) Seriously though using a array of FileInfo is a nice alternative to using an array of strings since it gives you many more options